# if then inline with bash and makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to evaluate a variable inline in order to produce one output or the other for the command line.

Something like this (example):

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) 'if [[ "$(DEBUG)" == "FALSE" ]]; then echo $(INC_$(module)) else echo $(INCTWO_$(module)) fi;' $(LIBRARIES) ...
```

but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for bash within, er.. bash right. I've tried backtick like shown and [].

maybe a more clearer example:

```
ls 'if [[ "TRUE" == "FALSE" ]]; then echo " -al"; else echo " -b"; fi;'
```

Comment: Command substitution: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution.

Comment: Don't complicate your life with making the shell perform that check, do it in the makefile: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals

Comment: @4ae1e1 look at my second example. It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah, in the end I did it like that. I'm still interested to know the answer for original question though.

Comment: Did I link to the documentation? And did you read it? It you did you won't expect it to work, for any reason.

Comment: @4ae1e1 yes you did link to the documentation, which I've already read and I've read it again when you've linked it. I am not interpreting anything useful out of it, hence why I asked - because I don't understand how or why not. For example "Command substitutions may be nested"... Explain if you know how or explain better than documentation.

Comment: Command substitution syntax is `$()`, not putting the command in single quotes. `ls $(echo crap)`.

Comment: I've tried that as well: ls $(if [[ "TRUE" == "FALSE" ]]; then " -al"; else " -b"; fi;) and $(if [[ "TRUE" == "FALSE" ]]; then $(ls -al); else $(ls -b); fi;) and various other combinations. Nothing works.

Comment: `ls $(if [[ "TRUE" == "FALSE" ]]; then echo -al; else echo -b; fi)`. I'm definitely not promoting this type of usage, but it's not at all hard to write a syntactically and semantically correct command.

Comment: Thank you @4ae1e1 A man can sometimes be blind. that echo was wrong for me. Embarrassing.

Comment: the command substitution syntax clashes with the makefile variable syntax. I'm not sure your original concept is even possible. I am far from a makefile expert though.